# Where to find the violin for Agatha's Song in Vault 92?

Tags: fallout-3

I have explored all of Vault 92 running in circles yet I am unable to locate the violin. Where to find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sits on a table in the southwest section of the Sound Testing area.

[image: Screenshot of Local Map of Agatha's violin]

Comment: *"Yet I am unable to locate the violin"* - well that was fast.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Well, I did waste quite some time on the search. Yet asking a question in past tense seemed kind of ... odd.